# In jQuery Ajax, dataType: jsonp gives "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" while dataType:json works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

Below is the AJAX call using jsonp, I get "**SyntaxError: unterminated string literal**" in console.

this.API_DOMAIN is the 3rd party website. Thus using jsonp for cross domain. However same AJAX works fine with `dataType: json`.

The response has description which contains **'‘LIVE’“'** which the console gives an error.

But why does it work fine with **dataType : 'json'** and not with **dataType: 'jsonp'** ?

What can be the problem ?

```
var ajaxlink = this.API_DOMAIN+'callJson.php';
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxlink,
  type: 'GET',
  data:{
    oauth_token: this.API_KEY,
    id:eventId,
    moreInfo:'artistinfo,booking,multiplebooking',
    lang:LANG_DEFAULT
  },
  jsonpCallback: "aaaaa",
  cache: true,
  dataType:"jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    console.log("similar event success");
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(){
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try JSON.stringify the data check ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your string delimited by single quote or double quotes?
Special char should be escaped, and if it's multiline concatenatewith plus sign or backslash sign.
var s = "This is a very long string  \
the second part od the string";